# Manually copying MBR from one drive to the other GPT drive and configuring GRUB results in booting failure

Tags: boot, backup, boot-loader, grub-legacy

I run *CentOS 6.4*. I have **SSD** 300GB for system files and **RAID10 8TB** for storage + *backup*.

**SSD system drive is partitioned as follows:** `fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 300.1 GB, 300069052416 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 36481 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc95ec64f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1          66      524288   83  Linux       (/boot)
/dev/sdb2              66        8421    67108864   83  Linux       (/)
/dev/sdb3            8421       12598    33554432   83  Linux       (/usr)
/dev/sdb4           12598       36482   191847576    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5           12598       16775    33554432   83  Linux       (/var)
/dev/sdb6           16775       18864    16777216   83  Linux       (/tmp)
/dev/sdb7           18864       35574   134217728   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

**RAID10 8TB  *(GPT)* is partitioned as follows:** `parted /dev/sda print`

```
Model: ASR7805 RAID 10 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 7999GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      8389kB  7399GB  7399GB                  primary             (LUKS)
 2      7399GB  7400GB  510MB   ext4            primary  boot       (/boot)
 3      7400GB  7468GB  68.7GB  ext4            /                   (/)
 4      7468GB  7503GB  34.4GB  ext4            /usr                (/usr)
 5      7503GB  7537GB  34.4GB  ext4            /var                (/var)
 6      7537GB  7554GB  17.2GB  ext3            /tmp                (/tmp)
 7      7554GB  7692GB  137GB   linux-swap(v1)  primary             (swap)
 8      7692GB  7992GB  300GB                   primary             (LUKS)
```

All I wanted is just to use *300GB* of space on my */dev/sda (RAID10)* for creating an identical image (backup) of my *SSD* in case of sudden failure. As you could see above, I have partitioned my *RAID10* is just absolutely identical way as my current system *SSD*. Afterwards, I have created exact images of each partition that I have on my current *SSD* and extracted them to my *RAID10* using `dump/restore` commands.

All is fully copied and set on my *RAID10* just the same way as on my current *SSD*.

I have obviously edited my backed up `fstab` (on *RAID10 /etc/fstab*) using proper UUID for mounting on load.

**BUT**

Whatever I do I cannot properly load the system, as I restart and choose to load from *RAID10*. The system just doesn't boot (underscore is continually blinking)!?

I have tried to copy first `446` bite of boot sector `(dd if=/tmp/mbrsdb.bak of=/dev/sda bs=446 count=1)` from my *SSD's MBR* to my *RAID10's MBR* but it didn't work?

Now, as I'm all out of any other options, I would like to ask for your help?

Comment: A side note: using RAID arrays for backup is akin to storing your ammo near open fire... You'll never know when the house blows up.

Comment: Thanks, but at the same time you don't know when SSD fails? Having two resources failing at the same time - that is something outstanding, right? What are other options you could offer in my case? ;)

Comment: I have finally found out that I needed an extra partition on my *GPT RAID10* drive with a flag `bios_grub` that GRUB would use upon setup. It's clearly explained here, for those who's interested in more details: http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-Partitioning-EN-The-new-GPT-disk-layout

Comment: Glad for you. Please feel free to make it into an answer and accept it. Useful information for posterity and all that...

Comment: Good idea, I will do it when I have time..

Answer (score -2):

You need to install GRUB properly onto the corresponding disk properly, not only copy of MBR. For GRUB2 it's [grub-install](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html)

Comment: I have tried it! I have to install it on GPT. Regular methods fail! I'm missing something!? I get an error `The file /backup/boot/grub/stage1 not read correctly.`